# In python, how can i get part of string from an element of array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

For example, I have an array with string elements and I only want the first 3 characters:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array(['apples', 'foobar', 'cowboy'])
```

what can i do to obtain ['app', 'foo', 'cow']

I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
 >>> b = a[:],[0,2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
b = [a[i][:3] for i in range(len(a))]
print(b)
```

Output:

```
['app','foo','cow']
```

Comment: @0.B. Thanks for your accept, now you have more than 15 reputation so you can upvote if you want

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array(['apples', 'foobar', 'cowboy'])    
v = list(a)
b = [val[:3] for val in v]
print(b)
>>> ['app', 'foo', 'cow']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `map` like so:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array(['apples', 'foobar', 'cowboy'])
b = map(lambda string: string[:3], a)

print(b) # ['app', 'foo', 'cow']
```

One good thing about using this method is that if you want to do more complicated things to each element in the `numpy` array, you can just define a more sophisticated, one-argument function that takes in an element from that array and then spits out the desired data like so:

```
import numpy

def some_complex_func(element):
    """
    Do some complicated things to element here.
    """

    # In this case, only return the first three characters of each string
    return element[:3]

a = numpy.array(['apples', 'foobar', 'cowboy'])
b = map(some_complex_func, a)

print(b) # ['app', 'foo', 'cow']
```